# Meaning of とっぴょうしもねぇ

Tags: grammar, translation, expressions

Maruko stops a friend who is passing by and asks him if he ever receives year-end presents at his house. He replies:

> 「なんだよ急に、とっぴょうしもねぇこ**と**きく奴だなァ」

I am completely stuck on nearly all of this sentence.

1. なんだよ is "what!?" and 急に is "rapidly/abruptly". I assume they go together to make a new meaning other than "What!? Rapidly ...", otherwise there should be some punctuation after なんだよ.
2. This part I'm especially confused about. とっぴ is a na-adjective meaning "erratic". What on earth is the ょうしもねぇ part after it?
3. Is the と in bold the quote particle or part of こと? I feel it's the latter and there's a particle (を) missing.

The sentence gives me the feeling of

> "What!? You certainly are a person who abruptly asks random questions".

But I'm not at all confident.

Please can you break down this sentence so I can understand it?

Comment: That is 江戸言葉(or 江戸っ子言葉). It means Edo dialect.
「なんですか急に、とんでもないことを聞く人ですね」

Comment: http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E7%AA%81%E6%8B%8D%E5%AD%90%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84

Answer (score 7, accepted):

とっぴょうしもない is a fixed expression meaning "outrageous", "crazy" or "absurd". (Tip: When you see something with ねぇ try searching it with ない first.)

With more punctuation and less colloquialisms the sentence is

> なんだよ、急に。とっぴょうしもないこと［を］きく奴だね

- なんだよ is a way of voicing a complaint, like "WTF!" (but milder)
- 急に, like いきなり, means something like "out of the blue"
- こと nominalizes とっぴょうしもない

I don't know how to translate 奴 idiomatically, but literally it would be something like

> *lit.* Hey! [You're] someone asking absurd things.

Trying to make your "feeling" more literal:

> What the...!? You certainly are someone who asks absurd questions.

More colloquially you could go with "WTF!? Are you crazy?", although that's more confrontational than the original.